# Set space-between between flex list items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got a navigation which looks sort like a this one under, and `li` items inside are `flex` items. This menu is rendered from the outside, and I'm not able to wrap any of the items inside the dedicated container.

What I'm trying to achieve is to set `space-between` between the last item and the other ones on the left. I've tried to do it with a `margin-left` on the last child, but it's not a nicest solution.

Is there a CSS option to "wrap" the last item somehow, so there's always space between that one and the ones on the left?

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.last {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li class="last">Last Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you call margin-left solution as a "not-nicest"? It's a good practice, which is used frequently for this kind of tasks.

Comment: Margin solution is a good one: https://medium.com/@iamryanyu/how-to-align-last-flex-item-to-right-73512e4e5912

Comment: Yeah I know, but since the width of the screen will be different for different monitor sizes - with margin I can't make it stick to the left at all times

Comment: you need margin-left:auto on the last child (no need extra wrapper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `margin-left` on the last element is a **good solution**. However, you can *improve* your implementation by using the `:last-child` selector:

```
ul li:last-child {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Instead of manually assigning the `last` class to the last child.

**EDIT:** If you mean you want your last child to be aligned *all the way* to the right. You can separate them into different lists, and use `justify-content: space-between`:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

ul li {
  width: 3rem;
}

.right li {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="left">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="right">
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```